# Nonstandard django multi-select widget?

Tags: django, django-forms

Simple MultiSelect, FilteredSelectMultiple in Django admin is big for me and [ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects) inconvenient in this case, is there anything that's shown in the picture. Button add category - add antoher ManyToMany relation.

[image: multi-select]

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not positive what you're asking, but to me it looks like you need to create a custom widget for a many to many field and use that widget in the admin.

If you're looking for something out of the box that works exactly like this you're not going to find it.  You'll either have to find or write js/css to match what you need and include that in the ModelAdmin's media.  You'll need to override the widget used also in the ModelAdmin as well as writing the custom widget to render the appropriate HTML to match your design.